# FFmpeg -x265-params does not recognize qp value

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

I'm using `ffmpeg 20171115-ff8f40a version` to encode a `yuv` video using `x265` encoder.

My script is the one below:

```
ffmpeg -s:v 1440x1080 -r 25 -i incident_10d_1440x1080_25.yuv -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx265 -x265-params --qp 16 out_1440x1080_qp16.mp4
```

However I get the error: `[NULL @ 00000000007226a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '16' 16: Invalid argument`.

16 is the value I set for the quantization parameter from `x265-params`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

`x265-params` must be inserted in double quotes. Thus, my script should be like:

```
ffmpeg -s:v 1440x1080 -r 25 -i incident_10d_1440x1080_25.yuv -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx265 -x265-params "--qp 16" out_1440x1080_qp16.mp4
```